# SQL Server Persisted computed columns versus actual (normal) column

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns

I have a question about persisted computed columns versus actual (normal) column.

I thought that the usage of computed columns was mainly to not physically store the values. But when it's persisted, what are the pros and cons versus a normal column in a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of persisted computed columns as computed columns with a cache that saves you the resources to compute the result every time you query it.

The main advantage over normal columns is that you don't need to manage them yourself (after the initial definition). With a normal column, you'd have to make sure its value is properly calculated on each insert or update, and make sure it can't be directly updated itself. With a persisted calculated column, the database does the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: When does SQL Server recalculate computed columns? How does it know when they're stale?

Comment: @Dai basically the same way it knew how to calculate the value in the first place. The column's value is calculated from a formula that can refer to other columns, function calls and literal values. When one of the other columns is changed, the computed column's value is recalculated.